# I have a problem while installing Odoo v13. requirements.txt. Related with Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools

Tags: python, windows, odoo, c++builder, setuptools

I'm trying to install Odoo v13 dependencies, but it fail with the next error.

```
pip install -r ..\Odoo\13\odoo\requirements.txt
```

[image: Install odoo requirements]

Seeing this, I tryed to install manually greenlet v0.4.10 (which is the version I need)
And It says that the problem is with Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools. I tryed to install It and this happends (I reinstalled Microsoft Visual Studio Installer and Microsoft Visual C++ 2015):

```
pip install greenlet==0.4.0.
```

It shows me the next output:

```
Collecting greenlet==0.4.10
  Using cached greenlet-0.4.10.zip (82 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for greenlet, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: greenlet
    Running setup.py install for greenlet ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\aresua\documents\vscodeprojects\odoo-13-addons\.venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aresua\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xxf1xvcp\\greenlet_2223126928944440ab06138578a156c0\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aresua\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xxf1xvcp\\greenlet_2223126928944440ab06138578a156c0\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\aresua\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-f2n6j60w\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\aresua\documents\vscodeprojects\odoo-13-addons\.venv\include\site\python3.6\greenlet'
         cwd: C:\Users\aresua\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xxf1xvcp\greenlet_2223126928944440ab06138578a156c0\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'greenlet' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\aresua\documents\vscodeprojects\odoo-13-addons\.venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aresua\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xxf1xvcp\\greenlet_2223126928944440ab06138578a156c0\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aresua\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xxf1xvcp\\greenlet_2223126928944440ab06138578a156c0\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\aresua\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-f2n6j60w\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\aresua\documents\vscodeprojects\odoo-13-addons\.venv\include\site\python3.6\greenlet' Check the logs for full command output.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/microsoft-visual-c-140/6f0726e2-6c32-4719-9fe5-aa68b5ad8e6d), if you're using Windows, install MS visual C++ with: https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vs_buildtools.exe
Then restart your PC.